# How i can get widgets areas working in customizer?

Tags: theme-development, themes, widgets, theme-customizer

I'm encountering a strange issue with WordPress. I'm building a theme and the theme customization is driven by Customizer.

So, basically in functions.php I'm adding

```
add_theme_support( 'widget-customizer' );
```

i'm registering a sidebar with:

```
register_sidebar( array(
   'name' => __( 'Test Sidebar' ),
   'id' => 'test-sidebar',
));
```

then in **index.php** i'm adding the common ***get_footer();*** and in ***footer.php*** I have:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'test-sidebar' ) ): ?>
    <div id="test-sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'test-sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now the **first** strange issue is that in the preview window I can see any widget added via admin page in *Appearance* but in the customizer widget section I can't see any area and I get this message

> There are no widget areas currently rendered in the preview. Navigate
>   in the preview to a template that makes use of a widget area in order
>   to access its widgets here.

But the **second** strange issue is that if in my functions.php I add:

```
   add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
       ?>
       <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'test-sidebar' ) ): ?>
            <div id="test-sidebar" class="sidebar">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'test-sidebar' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
    } );
```

Now I can see the widget area in customizer.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This is how the good question should look like.

Comment: Thanks @prosti. Furthermore it's still not a very good question because the question isn't direct and it not point to an argument like stack community want. But I'm struggling with this problem.

Comment: @koMah I'm not sure if `widget-customizer` is a valid argument for `add_theme_support()`. Do you have any additional plugins installed?

Comment: No @Sven, clean Wordpress install, without plugins.

Comment: @koMah, actually your question was sufficient for the good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a entire night I've get the answer.
Reflecting on why the customizer showing me the widget areas only through the **wp_footer** hook I have checked my ***footer.php*** and the problem was that ***wp_footer()*** were called before the sidebar section.

```
   /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
    * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
    * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
    */
    wp_footer();
```

Moving it after sidebars all works perfectly.

Comment: That's right. The `wp_footer` action must fire in the preview so that `customize-preview.js` will be printed along with all of the other supporting data and scripts for the customizer preview to interface with the customizer controls pane.

Comment: Hey @WestonRuter, i know you!! You're a great with customizer. Did you know how dynamic Menu Locations can be refreshed in customizer? I have opened a ticket [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39040)

Comment: hey, dynamic menu locations are not supported currently. You'll need to register then unconditionally. However, you can hide the controls for them via adding an `active_callback` for their controls in the customizer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `wp_footer()` hook is important. 
If you remove `wp_footer` hook from the ***footer.php*** file you will get the message from `class-wp-customize-widgets.php`.

> There are no widget areas currently rendered in the preview. Navigate in the preview to a template that makes use of a widget area in order to access its widgets here.

If you remove the `wp_footer` hook the whole customizer section will be there, but it will not work as @WestonRuter pointed, because of  `customize-preview.js` will not be there.

---

I would just provide few tips:

You don't need to add `add_theme_support( 'widget-customizer' );`
`widget-customizer` plugin is an integral part of WordPress core now, and you have that support ready.

The other thing, `footer.php` is probably not the smartest place to put your sidebar organization-wise. You may check the `twentysixteen` WordPress theme, to see the organization.